# How can I have more than 1 propertyWrapper for a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have some propertyWrapper that I want to apply them to a variable. Below is my code:

```
@propertyWrapper struct Capitalized {
    var wrappedValue: String { didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized } }
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized
    } 
}

@propertyWrapper struct Trimmed {
    var wrappedValue: String { didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) } }
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

**Use Case:**

```
@Capitalized @Trimmed var testValue: String = "     hello, world!  "
```

**Errors:**

> Cannot convert value of type 'Trimmed' to specified type 'String'
>
> Composed wrapper type 'Trimmed' does not match former 'wrappedValue' type 'String'

How we can have more than one propertyWrapper?
As you can read the question I looking to have more than 1 propertyWrapper, hopping it is clear to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the type of the `wrappedValue` given to `Capitalized` ends up being a `Trimmed`, and not the `String` that's within the `Trimmed`.

You can see that for yourself by building a little debugging wrapper:

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct InspectType<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T

    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        print("The type of the `wrappedValue` is: \(T.self)")
    }
}

struct Sample {
    @InspectType @Trimmed var testValue: String = "     hello, world!  "
}

_ = Sample() // prints: "The type of the `wrappedValue` is: Trimmed"
```

You need to generalize your `Capitalized` to handle both a `String`, and another "`String`-like" thing. I think `LosslessStringConvertible` seems like a decent choice to describe a "`String`-like" thing, so I'll go with that. Here's how I would do this:

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct Capitalized<S: LosslessStringConvertible> {
    private var storage: S

    public var wrappedValue: S {
        get { storage }
        set { storage = S.init(newValue.description.capitalized)! }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: S) {
        self.storage = S.init(wrappedValue.description.capitalized)!
    }
}
```

Which gives us this error:

> error: generic struct `Capitalized` requires that `Trimmed` conform to `LosslessStringConvertible`

Which makes sense, because in the compositional case of `@Capitalized @Trimmed var testValue`, the property wrappers will have a nest type like `Capitlaized<Trimmed>`. Naturally, we just need to define that conformance:

```swift
extension Trimmed: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { self.wrappedValue }
}

extension Trimmed: LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ string: String) {
        self.init(wrappedValue: string)
    }
}
```

Now it works!

```
struct Sample {
    @Trimmed var trimmedString: String = "     hello, world!  "
    @Capitalized var capitalizedString: String = "     hello, world!  "
    @Capitalized @Trimmed var testValue: String = "     hello, world!  "
}

print(Sample().testValue) // prints "Hello, World!"
```

You might notice however, that the inverse composition doesn't work:

```
struct Sample {
    // ❌ error: cannot convert value of type 'Capitalized<String>' to specified type 'String'
    @Trimmed @Capitalized var inverted: String = "     hello, world!  "
}
```

If we want this to work, we need to do the same generifying of `Trimmed`. Here's how that might look, all together:

```swift
import Foundation

@propertyWrapper struct Capitalized<S: LosslessStringConvertible> {
    private var storage: S

    public var wrappedValue: S {
        get { storage }
        set { storage = S.init(newValue.description.capitalized)! }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: S) {
        self.storage = S.init(wrappedValue.description.capitalized)!
    }
}

extension Capitalized: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { self.wrappedValue.description }
}

extension Capitalized: LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ string: String) {
        self.init(wrappedValue: S(string)!)
    }
}

@propertyWrapper struct Trimmed<S: LosslessStringConvertible> {
    private var storage: S

    public var wrappedValue: S {
        get { storage }
        set { storage = S.init(newValue.description.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))! }
    }

    init(wrappedValue: S) {
        self.storage = S.init(wrappedValue.description.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!
    }
}

extension Trimmed: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { self.wrappedValue.description }
}

extension Trimmed: LosslessStringConvertible {
    init?(_ string: String) {
        self.init(wrappedValue: S(string)!)
    }
}

struct Sample {
    @Trimmed var trimmedString: String = "     hello, world!  "
    @Capitalized var capitalizedString: String = "     hello, world!  "
    @Capitalized @Trimmed var testValue: String = "     hello, world!  "
    @Trimmed @Capitalized var inverted: String = "     hello, world!  "
}

print(Sample().inverted)
```

Comment: What I think it should be done is just converting or changing `Trimmed`  to `String` again for get used for `@Capitalized`, which I am working on to use a Custom protocol for this work, I am not finished my investigation on this issue, but this that I have to use LosslessStringConvertible or CustomStringConvertible is not a must, the String is just enough with combination with a custom protocol.

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible, because Swift doesn’t let you define implicit conversions (unlike e.g. C#), and you don’t have any opportunity to call a method to transform the type.

Comment: I have working code right now, just with Swift and using String and a custom Protocol. I can do even this: `@Bracket @Capitalized @Trimmed var testValue: String = "     hello, world!  " // [Hello, World!]`

Comment: Interesting, I'd love to see it when you're done!